# Function defined over all a set (NOTATION)

Tags: functions, notation

I want to write down symbolically a function that is defined over a set (all the set, no just an element of it) to the natural numbers.

The function is something like this:
For example $X\subset \mathbb{Z}^+$ is a set with finite number of elements. My function $R(\cdot)$ take the set $X$ and draw an element from it at random. For example $R(\{1,2,3\})=2$

I want to use the notation $$f : A \to B$$
But i don't know what to put in the place of $A$.

Comment: so you want a symbolic notation for a function which maps the entirety of A To B?

Comment: The power set of $\mathbb{Z}$? Or $\{A\}$?

Comment: "*My function $R(\cdot)$ take the set $X$ and draws an element from it* **at random**."  Are you saying that at times $R(\{1,2,3\})=2$ *and at other times* $R(\{1,2,3\})=1$?  If so, then this is not a *function* because it is not well-defined.  What you may be looking for is instead a *random variable*.

Comment: Oh, yes. You are right. I might use "application" instead of "function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use power set:

$R: \mathcal{P}(A) \to A$ such that $R(X) \in X$.

Another notation to power set is $2^A$.

If you're thinking some function that each time associate each subset to a element, it's something like

$R: \mathbb{Z} \times \mathcal{P}(A) \to A$ such that $R(X) \in X$.

Where $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ can simulate time/events.

If you're thinking a function that take JUST ONE value: associate JUST $A$ to an element (and not all subsets of $A$ to an element), it is

$R: \{A\} \to A$

Comment: It's a choice function.

Comment: is $R: \{ A\} \to A $ equivalent to $R: \mathcal{P}(A) \to A$?

Comment: $\{ A\}$ is a set with just one element: the set $A$. $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is the set of ALL subsets of $A$. For example, if $A = \{0,1,2\}$, them $\mathcal{P}(A) = \{\varnothing, \{0\}, \{1\} , \{2\}, \{0,1\}, \{0.2\}, \{1,2\}, A \}$. Note: $card (\mathcal{P}(A)) = 2^{card(A)}$, this is one reason to use $2^A$.

Comment: Another reason is that a subset of $A$ can be modeled by a function: $\chi_X: A \to {0,1}$ such that $\chi_X(a) = 0$ if $a \in X$ and $\chi_X(a)=1$ if $a \in A\setminus X$. In a set-theoretic construction of $\mathbb{N}$, $2 = \{0,1\}$.  Then, the power-set of A is in one-to-one correspondence with the set of function from $A$ to $2$, i.e., $2^A$.

Answer (score 1):

$f:2^A\rightarrow B$ defines a function that maps every subset of $A$ to an element of $B$.

Comment: its either this or he means f is surjective.